# Domain of convergence of power series-2

Tags: power-series

Here is the series:

$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x-3)^n}{(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)n}
$$

What is the interval of convergence?
I tried using root test and ratio test but finding the limit from thereon is quite difficult.

From root test: 
$$
\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{|x-3|}{(\sqrt[n]{\sqrt[n]{n}-1)n}}
$$

Comment: How about $$n^{1/n} \sim 1+{\frac {\ln  \left( n \right) }{n}}+{\frac { \left( \ln 
 \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}}{2{n}^{2}}}+O \left( {n}^{-3} \right) $$

Comment: Let me try it out...

Comment: I don't think its a very solid way of doing it because it leads to 0^0??

Comment: For inside the interval of convergence how about applying GEdgar suggestion together with alternating series test?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go for the root test:
$$
r=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|(x-3)|}{\sqrt[n]{(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)n}}
$$
So we have to calculate the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)n}}
$$
Form here on, there is a mundane way to show that the limit is one. The direct path is using multiple Hopital. But we give another proof:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}}{\sqrt[n]{\sqrt[n]{n}-1}}
$$
It can be shown that ${\sqrt[n]{n}}$ goes to 1 as $n\to\infty$. For the other limit, see that:
$$
\frac{\ln n}{n}\leq \sqrt[n]{n}-1\leq n\implies  \sqrt[n]{\frac{\ln n}{n}}\leq \sqrt[n]{\sqrt[n]{n}-1}\leq \sqrt[n]{n}
$$
Now you can show that both limits of LHS and RHS go to 1 as $n\to\infty$ and therefore the limit in the middle exists and is equal to one and hence the final limit exists and is 1.

In any case the domain of convergence is:
$$
{|(x-3)|}<1
$$
with the point $x=4$.

---

**Remark 1:**
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{\ln n}{n}}=L\implies \frac{1}{n}\ln(\frac{\ln n}{n}) =\ln L\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln({\ln n})-\ln({n})}{n}=0\implies L=1.
$$

**Remark 2:** If $x-3=-1$, the series becomes:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^{2n}\frac{1}{(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)n}
$$
Such series with positive non-increasing terms converges iff $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converges. Hence:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{(\sqrt[n]{2^n}-1)2^n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1}\to\infty
$$
Therefore it diverges.

For the case were $x-3=1$, we get an alternating series with non-increasing absolute value of its terms and according to [the alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) it converges.

Comment: The step to prove that the limit is 1 using L'hopitals is really long and infeasible

Comment: There are easier ways as mentioned in the comments. Know that ${\sqrt[n]{n}}$ goes to 1 as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I know that...thanks for your alternative

Comment: I added something to the answer.

Comment: What did you add?--Its by the Squeeze Theorem

Comment: Explain how you ruled out cases $|x-3|=1$.

Comment: I think a proper proof that the LHS goes to 1 is also needed since it is an inderminate form

Comment: @GEdgar, Very good point indeed. Added to the answer.

Comment: The OP did say *interval* of convergence, so I will let you off the hook concerning the rest of the circle $|x-3|=1$ in the complex plane.

Comment: Yes, I had the same impression from OP.